# How to Deploy an Isolated App Service Environment with ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, paas, azure-rm-template, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Does anyone know what values need to be used in an ARM template to deploy an Isolated (e.g I3) App Service Environment. I can deploy manually through the portal and then deploy I series service plans but I can only get P series ASEs through an ARM template, looking at resource manager doesn't enlighten me. Here is the ASE section of my template:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
  "name": "ase1",
  "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
  "location": "North Europe",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "properties": {
    "name": "ase1",
    "location": "North Europe",
    "ipSslAddressCount": 0,
    "internalLoadBalancingMode": "Web",
    "dnsSuffix": "somedns.co.uk",
    "virtualNetwork": {
      "Id": "someVNetId",
      "Subnet": "somesubnetName"
    },
    "multiSize": "Standard_D1_V2",
    "multiRoleCount": 2,
    "workerPools": [
      {
        "workerSizeId": 0,
        "workerSize": "Small",
        "workerCount": 0
      },
      {
        "workerSizeId": 1,
        "workerSize": "small",
        "workerCount": 0
      },
      {
        "workerSizeId": 2,
        "workerSize": "small",
        "workerCount": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: so whats the question, you are deploying your ase, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but to deploy ASEv1 vs ASEv2 use the `kind` property.

```
    {
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "VirtualNetwork": {
                "Id": "[parameters('vnetId')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                "Subnet": "[parameters('subnetName')]"
            },
            "dnsSuffix": "xxx",
            "internalLoadBalancingMode": # None, Publishing or Web
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceenvironments/createorupdate#definitions_internalloadbalancingmode
        },
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-02-01",
        "kind": ASEV2 or ASEV1 (for old ASE)
    }
```